# Creating edge collection in ArangoDb FOXX app

Tags: arangodb

Can somebody help me with following issue.
I'm writing custom FOXX app in ArangoDB and I need to create edge collection.
With `db._create("example");` I can create document collection, but I don't know how to change the type of it. I've tried `db._create("example", {type: "edge"});` but it doesn't work.

In [documentation](https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/HandlingCollections.html#HandlingCollectionsIntro) is written

> Collections have a type that is specified by the user when the collection is created. There are currently two types: document and edge. The default type is document.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

db._createEdgeCollection("example");

Should solve your problem.

I suggest using the cheat sheet: https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/shell_reference_card.pdf

Comment: That link is dead